# How cookies are handled in react-native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, passport.js

I have a web app running with node js and passport.js and the authentication flow is working well.
I'm trying to develop a react-native and to make the same authentication flow (with passport.js).

I changed the passport code to redirect back to the react-native app (with Linking) and it worked.

so the flow is:

1. Open browser with the login url (/auth/google)
2. User logged in
3. Redirected back to native app
4. send a request to verify the user is logged in - but the user is not logged in, I think because the cookies were not sent to the server

I also tried adding to the fetch credentials "same-origin" or "include" but still the user is not logged in.

Some code I used:

```
Linking.openURL("http://<my ip>:3000/auth/google"); //for log in

app.get('/auth/google/callback', //handle the log in with passport js
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        failureRedirect: '/login'
    }), function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('MyApp://login); // redirect back to native app
    });

fetch("http://<my ip>:3000/api1", {credentials: /*"same-origin"*/"include"}) //get 401 -> user is not logged in
```

Am I missing anything?

How cookies are handled in react-native? Is it like in the web? how the cookies should be passed from the browser to the native app after redirect?

Answer (score 0):

React Native is not browser environment. It doesn't automatically handle cookies like browsers.

You have to use some cookie-aware request library such as [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent).

Example usage (from [superagent documentation](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#saving-cookies)):

```
const agent = request.agent();
agent
  .post('/login')
  .then(() => {
    return agent.get('/cookied-page');
  });
```

Then all requests from `agent` will handle cookies automatically (shares the same cookie jar).

Comment: Not sure I understand.
So I will use this superagent in react-native for all of my requests to server.
But my login process is not within the react-native, it's from the browser talking with passport and then redirected back to the app, so I'm not sure it will work.
In your example, the login process is in the react-native code.

Comment: For best practice, you should use [bearer token authentication](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer) for native mobile app instead of cookie. If you use cookie, then it's a bit tricky to bring cookies from external browser to your app.

Comment: Thanks, seems like bearer authentication is the best solution, I will give it a try.